# Buttons' CSS won't change

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

This is probably a duplicate, but none of the answers I have seen helped.

Basically, i'm using Foundation 5 right now, and I want to make some buttons with custom colors.

This is the code I am using to try and change the colors of my button.

```
button.&0, .button.&0 {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: 000000;
    color: white;
}
```

I'm not a professional website developer, but I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: I don't think `&` is a valid css class name character

Answer (score 8):

You should use a better selector (without invalid characters)

```
 <button id="uniqueButton" class="buttonStyle"></button>
```

and then use the following code to style all buttons in the same style:

```
button.buttonStyle {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
    color: white;
}
```

OR if you only want that specific button to be styled

```
#uniqueButton{
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #000000;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Hm.  It's only 1 button that I need to be that way, so I used the ID, but that didn't change anything either.  And I changed the "&0" to "and0" as well.

Comment: Svenisok, "border-color" whithout "border-style" does not do anything visually... Try to be more complete ;) You are awesome though ... :p

Comment: Mabe you should add a width and a height in your style.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define the border like this.

```
#and0{
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    color: white;
}
```